# Efficiently filtering a python list with respect to values from a second list (of tuples)

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the most efficient solution to do the following:

I have two lengthy lists:

```
a = [3, 7, 89, 1, ....] #list of user_ids
b = [(2,t1),(3,t2),(2,t3),(89,t4), ....] # list of user_id, epoch_time pairs
```

The objective is to retrieve all members of list `a` if they exist in list `b` (i.e. in the first member of each tuple in list `b`). Note that a `user_id` may exist in multiple tuples in `b`.

One can fulfill this requirement like so:

```
result = []
for user_id in a:
    for uid,epoch_time in b:
        if user_id == uid:
            result.append(user_id)
return result
```

The question is, is there any way to do this faster than **O(n^2)**? E.g. via perhaps reorganizing `b` as a dictionary, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reorganize `b` as a dictionary as you mentioned, then check if `user_id` from `a` is available in the dictionary.

```
a = [3, 7, 89, 1]
b = [(2,'t1'),(3,'t2'),(2,'t3'),(89,'t4')]
dic = {k: v for k, v in b}
result = [x for x in a if dic.get(x)]
```

`dic.get(x)` returns `None` if `x` is not a key.

Comment: user_ids in `b` are not unique - notice how `(2,'t1')` and `(2,'t3')` are present in `b`. That won't cleanly translate over to a dictionary just like that, would it?

Comment: It will save the last `value` encountered for the same `key`, which is `2: 't3'` but that is ok if you are using the dict just to see if user id exists or not

Comment: If you want to convert `b` to a dictionary permanently, you can assign a `list` of `epoch_time` for each user and append to it, for example: `{2: ['t1', 't2', 't3']}`

Comment: Yea that would be a better approach

Comment: How are you creating `b` in the first place? if you can post the code we can tweak it to be a dictionary

Answer (score 1):

You can use a set which allows for O(1) checking that an element is part of it (or not).

```
result = []
set_a = set(a)
for uid, epoch_time in b:
    if uid in set_a:
        result.append(uid)
```

If you want unique values in the result, you can use a set for `result` as well:

```
result = set()
set_a = set(a)
for uid, epoch_time in b:
    if uid in set_a:
        result.add(uid)
```

which could even be turned into a list at the end:

```
result = list(result)
```

Comment: Wouldn't this allow duplicate values?

Comment: @AnthonyPham: it would, the question doesn't really state what's desired so I've updated my answer regarding that.

Answer (score 1):

For O(1), just check if the value is in the list `a` to start with:

```
result = []
for uid,epoch_time in b:
    if uid in a:
        result.append(uid)
```

If you don't want duplicate values, then add a condition that not only must the `uid` be in `a` but is not already existing in `result`:

```
result = []
for uid,epoch_time in b:
    if uid in a and uid not in result:
        result.append(uid)
```

[Try it here!](https://repl.it/Jo62/1)

Answer (score 0):

I would use sets.  Since you are just ditching the epoch date.

```
a = [3, 7, 89, 1, ....]
b = [(2,t1),(3,t2),(2,t3),(89,t4), ....]

def fn(a, b):
    a = set(a)
    b_uid, trash = zip(*b)
    b_uid = set(b_uid)
    return a.intersection(b)
```

This all the speed of dictionary without dealing with the values.
Also fix the return type to be whatever you want.  (wrap it in a list if that is what you want back.